# Can someone explain how this C code calculate 2^n?

Tags: c++, algorithm, math

Here's the code that does the trick. I do know the concept how to calculate m^n in O(logn) time, and I think it's related, but how?

```
for(long long int i = 2; N; N /= 2, i *= i){
    if(N & 1){
        ans *= i;
    }
}
```

Comment: yet another "i know how this works but how does it work" question. oh well. just noting, if you really had stumbled on this code and had deduced that it's probably about "calculate m^n in O(log n) time", then you *would not have had to ask*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's the [square and multiply algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring).

N /= 2 has the effect of removing the lowest bit (and when all the bits remaining are zero, the algorithm is finished).

N & 1 checks if the lowest bit is odd or even

Answer (score 1):

It basically works the same way log N time m power n algorithm works.
Just trace the code for these two sets of input:

P.S:ans should be set to 1.

1. n=2
2. n=3

I am sure you will get it.